# Login issue with tank_auth (codeigniter authentication library)

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I have a php(with codeigniter framework) website which is using tank_auth.

My problem is, I can register and login in localhost but whenever I try to login in my host, login doesn't work. Same code, same database, same everything. No error messages, just reloads the login page when I click "let me in" button. Register is working great, other database read/write stuff are working great but when I'm trying to login, it just reloads the page.

My main frustration is, exactly same project is working on localhost perfectly. Do you have any idea why?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got this.

There are $config['phpass_hash_portable'] = FALSE; line on tank_auth config. I change it to TRUE and my problem is solved. Description is in the comments of the config file.

UPDATE: I think this is not enough for solving the problem. Since I got two projects, I encountered with the same problem on the other one and it worked when I changed

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

AND

```
$config['phpass_hash_portable'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things, but start with your config.php file.  Try setting:

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Ok I got this.

There are $config['phpass_hash_portable'] = FALSE; line on tank_auth config. I change it to TRUE and my problem is solved. Description is in the comments of tank_auth config file.

Thank you anyway.